# Running Watin on TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, watin

I'm trying to run a simple Watin test through TeamCity but the Internet Explorer window is never shown as is usually is via CruiseControl.

I get an error that it can't find a text field so something is running. But i can't see what without the window.

Is there a specific change to the setup of TeamCity server that I need to do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found this on [another forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5259538)

All credits go to Matt Baker

For future reference to anyone who attempts to run WatiN tests automatically using TeamCity.  You must start your build agent using `\bin\agent.bat start` and NOT as a service.  WatiN requires a full UI to execute properly and it doesn't get this environment as a service.  I hope this makes it easier for other people!

Comment: Is there any chance you could elaborate on how to do this? I have a TC 4 server running with multiple builds, only one of which will be using WaTiN. Could you provide a more in-depth walk-through on how to do this?

Comment: this ain't true, a service can indeed use the full UI, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488443/running-watin-on-teamcity/3415992#3415992

Comment: @Ruben: Or you could also just google "Matt Baker Watin", c'mon y'all! :) http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5259538

Comment: @Zidad And then you edit what you so easily found into the answer above to save others the bother, wahey!

Comment: @Ruben them folks down here ain't giv'n me no edit privileges no more :)

Comment: @Zidad The lazyweb has it sorted - it's lookin mighty fine now, thanks :D

Answer (score 20):

Under Account tab on the Teamcity Agent's Service property window (`services.msc`), check "Allow service to interact with desktop", that will allow local service account to spawn internet explorer. But you will most certainly get stuck with other stuff, like cookie blocking, password saving etc. so login as local service and fix those stuff.

Easiest way to do that is with `psexec` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), call `psexec -i -s cmd.exe` so spawn a cmd running as local account, then start internet explorer at setup everything up (the privacy settings in IE for local account is extremely high).

Comment: This actually worked fine for me and enabled me to run Watin commands without resorting to running TeamCity from a command line.

Comment: Note: in order for this work, you really need to pay attention to Carl's comment about "like cookie blocking, password saving, etc".  One more thing to add to that is making sure your domains are added to Trusted Sites.

Comment: Another thing: be careful if you are utilizing CORS at all... Local System does *not* like you using it with IE 9.  You will most likely run into "access denied" type errors.  I haven't yet found a way to get around it.

Comment: Why don't you just change the login user for the service to a local user on the system?

Answer (score 3):

If you installed as a service, make sure to stop it and disable it. Then, create a .bat file with the following

```
C:
cd teamcity\buildagent\bin\
agent.bat start
```

Now just create a shortcut in your start up folder to this batch file!

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop agent service. execute command: net stop TCBuildAgent from console.
2. Run from console  c:\teamcity\buildagent\bin\agent.bat
   start  (depending on your teamcity
   installation path)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this simple solution:
Go to services, edit the properties of your service, select the LogOn Tab, and check the box with the label:  "Allow service to interact with desktop".

Worked for me in bamboo.

Cheers,
Pedro O Moleiro